# how do i check if a win10 toast notification button was pressed?

Tags: c#, windows, toast

I'm trying to make a simple console program that runs a Toast notification and I got stuck at checking if a button is pressed

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new ToastContentBuilder()
                .AddText("test")
                .AddText("this is a test")
                .AddButton(new ToastButton()
                    .SetContent("test1")
                    .AddArgument("action", "test1")
                    .SetBackgroundActivation())
                .AddButton(new ToastButton()
                    .SetContent("test2")
                    .AddArgument("action", "test2")
                    .SetBackgroundActivation())
                .Show();
        }
        
    }
}
```

this will display a notification with 2 buttons called "test1" and "test2"

[image]

but i have no idea how to check button presses. I tried looking at the docs but i can't really understand it, i tried searching for videos on this topic but didn't really find anything useful

[note: I'm a minor and new to c# so I might need links to tutorials to understand specific things]

Comment: @Charlieface But the issue is that i don't know how to use this, and i don't know what to search for since I'm new to c#

Comment: Apparently there is an `OnActivated` event in your app somewhere https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/f5231bfb-5aea-4350-9354-1f53e07fb1bf/y

Comment: @Charlieface it mentions "App.xaml.cs" which i don't have since I'm trying to make this in a console

Comment: It's here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.notifications.toastnotificationmanagercompat.onactivated?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0 I think you need to call `ToastNotificationManagerCompat.CreateToastNotifier` then catch the event

Comment: @Charlieface I'm sorry, but it's pretty hard for me to understand how I'm supposed to use this. Could you link a tutorial or something i could follow, that explains how this works and how i can use it?

Comment: Never done this so no idea really, guessing in the dark here. Try create a field for the manager `private ToastNotificationManagerCompat _manager = ToastNotificationManagerCompat.CreateToastNotifier();` then in `Main` add the handler `_manager.OnActivated += OnActivated;` then you need to create the event handler function `private void OnActivated(ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgsCompat e) { // whatever }`

Comment: Have a look at this. Microsoft tells you how to do it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=desktop

Comment: @N0m4n904 that is where i started, it still does not help with the issue that i couldnt figure out how to get a button press to just run a function or something, also this post is a year old

Answer (score 0):

For me on WPF it works like this:

Add the following Code to your `OnStartup` Method in `App.xaml.cs`

```
ToastNotificationManagerCompat.OnActivated += toastArgs => {

      ToastArguments args = ToastArguments.Parse(toastArgs.Argument);

      var userInput = toastArgs.UserInput;

      Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate {

          switch (args["action"]) {

               case "test1":

                   // Your Code here...
 
                   break;
               case "test2":

                   // Your Code here...

                   break;
        }
   });
};
```